# Where is Apache getting date-time from?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost

I am deploying my (PHP, MySQL) app on client local machine. For Expiry I am comparing current date with start date & End Date in DB. If current date is between start date & end date than fine go ahead, other wise user will not be able to login.
How would user By PASS my app expiry logic. I need to know possible tricks where user can bypass my app so that I work on it and make expiry unbeatable.
I need to know from where Apache is taking current date. if from OS then user can change it & bypass my app.

Comment: Are you asking if the "current date" used to compare to the stored date is obtained from the client (which would allow the user to modify it) or is obtained server side (which the user has no access to). This would depend on you application & the query you use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for: `date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

You can also set this in your php.ini config.